# How to import a js file inside another js file just like how we import css file inside another css file

Tags: jquery

I would like to know how to import a .js file inside another .js file just like how we import css file inside another css file

all.css file goes like this.....

```
     @import "simple1.css";
     @import "simple2.css";
     @import "simple3.css";
     @import "simple4.css";
```

same way i wanna import js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js in my custom.js file

custom.js file goes like this

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

    $("#AddImage").html("<img src='"+clientID+".jpg'/>");

    });
```

i don't want to include js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js like

```
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
```

i want to include it in my custom.js file.

Please help! Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/include-javascript-file-inside-javascript-file

Comment: no it didnt work for me.... is there some simple code to import it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create function like below.

```
function importJs(url)
{
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = url;

    head.appendChild(script);
}
```

to run the code, see example below

```
importJs("myScript.js");
```

Now you can use `importJs()` in your any js. Which you can use for JS , similar to `@import` in CSS.

Answer (score 2):

this code worked for me using jQuery

```
$.getScript("myscript.js");
```

Answer (score 1):

Ther is this plugin http://code.google.com/p/jquery-include/. This jQuery plugin provides browser based file include similar to SSI.

```
$(document).includeReady(function () {

        // initialisation code here
        // e.g. modify include dom

});
```

And to use it

```
<span data-src="includes/test1.html">

        <p class="error-msg">include has not loaded</p>

</span>
```